# Column doesn't scroll when keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to develop my next Android App with [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). I know it is new and in Alpha state.

With this code, I want to implement a login view. It works so far until the keyboard opens :-(

[image]

```kotlin
private val items = listOf(Tab.Home)

private sealed class Tab(@StringRes val resourceId: Int) {
    object Home : Tab(R.string.home)
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            TopAppBar(
                                title = {
                                    Text(text = "Home")
                                }
                            )
                        },
                        bottomBar = {
                            BottomNavigation {
                                items.forEach { screen ->
                                    BottomNavigationItem(
                                        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, null) },
                                        label = { Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId)) },
                                        selected = true,
                                        onClick = { /* ... */
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ) {
                        Column(
                            Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).padding(16.dp)
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Lorem ipsum ...")
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
                            Text(text = "Lorem ipsum ...")
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
                            Text(text = "Lorem ipsum ...")
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
                            TextField(
                                value = "",
                                label = { Text("Name", color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary.copy(alpha = 0.5f)) },
                                onValueChange = { /*TODO*/ },
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                            TextField(
                                value = "",
                                label = { Text("Password", color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary.copy(alpha = 0.5f)) },
                                onValueChange = { /*TODO*/ },
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                            Button(
                                content = { Text("Login") },
                                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use this vertical scrollable column, but it doesn't scroll if parts of the column are behind the keyboard.

To fix it, I added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` in the manifest.

Now I can scroll the column but on top of the keyboard is also the bottomBar. And the bottomBar covers the login button at the bottom of the column. The bottomBar also covers the button if the content is enough that it also scrolls if the keyboard is closed.

[image]

Now I have three questions:

1. How to make the column scrollable when the keyboard opens but without the bottomBar on top of the keyboard?
2. How to implement an auto-scroll to the focused text field?
3. How to prevent the bottomBar from covering the button?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ChiragMittal no

Comment: Here is a similar thread with an answer that I posted
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66249829/jetpack-compose-scroll-to-focused-composable-in-column/67878918#67878918

Comment: Make sure to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in activity scope, but not in application

Comment: @JurijPitulja's answer in his comment worked for me.

Comment: hop this can help: https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/#controlling-the-ime-on-screen-keyboard

Comment: Try [this fix](https://github.com/litoco/Docs/tree/main/AndroidDocs/jetpack-compose/lazy-column/encountered-problems/lazy-column-items-hidden-by-keyboard) it may help

Comment: Im having this issue. Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120) (at least with LazyColumn in my experience). Please feel free to star that bug.

In that thread there's a hacky solution that involves `RelocationRequester` (which relocates a composable so it's visible) and `onfocusChanged` which tells you when to do the relocation.