# TextField is hiding under the keyboard when focused

Tags: android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, android-compose-textfield

I have a problem with TextField that is hiding under the keyboard, I've found the answers for the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66249829/jetpack-compose-scroll-to-focused-composable-in-column/67878918#67878918), but they are not helping me in my case. I have a LazyColumn with the list of different composables in it, and when I have not enough elements in the window for scroll to be activated, focusing on TextField is not lifting up focused TextField above keyboard. Keyboard just hides it.
My code:

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
typealias ComposableType = @Composable (Int) -> Unit
val uiList = listOf<ComposableType>( {IconButton}, {Text}, {CustomTextField(listState,it)}, {CustomTextField(listState,it)})
LazyColumn() {
    itemsIndexed(uiList) { index, ui ->
                ui.invoke(index)
        }
}

val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
@Composable
CustomTextField(scrollState: LazyListState, position: Int) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.onFocusEvent { focusState ->
            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                scope.launch {
                    scrollState.animateScrollToItem(position)
                }
            }
    )    
}
```

So, for example if i have 10 CustomTextFields in my uiList, scroll works when one of TextField is focused. But when there are only 2 TextFields in the uiList, focusing on either of them does not lift up them above keyboard.

Also I tried using RelocationRequester() and used Column with scroll instead of LazyColumn, none of it helped.

Comment: it looks like this google issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120?pli=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a combination of things...

1. You need to add this in your activity's declaration in Android.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

2. Use `BringIntoViewRequester` as modifier in your `TextField` as you mentioned.

```
.bringIntoViewRequester(yourBringIntoViewRequester)
```

3. The steps above worked for me when the component gain focus programatically (using `FocusRequester`). However, when the user taps on the TextField, it didn't work for me. So I implemented a workaround (which I'm not very proud of): when the `TextField` gain focus, I wait a bit to use the `RelocationRequester`. So I added this modifier to my `TextField`.

```
.onFocusEvent {
    if (it.isFocused) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            delay(200)
            yourBringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
        }
    }
}
```

These three things worked for me.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it worked in general, but i moved the last bit of code to onFocusChanged callback, otherwise it was jumping around.

Comment: It seems to me to be a bug of the framework, but adding the delay makes it work

Comment: It also only works for me with a delay... Did anyone bother reporting this on issue tracker, otherwise I will...

Comment: delay worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your activity in manifest file

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

And in the column for example use :

```
   Column (horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .navigationBarsPadding().imePadding()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .padding(top = 20.dp))
```

works for me , happy coding ..

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to add this in your activity's declaration in AndroidManifest.xml

   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
2. You have to set wrapContentHeight().navigationBarsWithImePadding() to the modifier of parent composable

   Column(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight().navigationBarsWithImePadding()){}

This solution worked for me.

Comment: What version of Jetpack Compose are you using? I cant find `navigationBarsWithImePadding()`

Comment: Though it's deprecated now in latest version.

Comment: What might have replaced it in the new version?

Comment: navigationBarsPadding().imePadding()