# How can I detect keyboard opening and closing in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The only way I've found in compose is to use `accompanist-insets` and that removes window insets. And such causes other problems with my app's layout.

The Android way seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device-or-not/26964010#26964010) and I could pass that into my compose app and act accordingly.

Is there another way in jetpack compose?

Comment: `WindowInsets.isImeVisible`

Comment: WindowInsets.isImeVisible works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way with Android's `viewTreeObserver`. It essentially is the Android version but it calls a callback that can be used in compose.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  var kbGone = false
  var kbOpened: () -> Unit = {}
  var kbClosed: () -> Unit = {}

  override fun onCreate(state: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(state)
    setContent {
      kbClosed = {
        // dismiss the keyboard with LocalFocusManager for example
      }
      kbOpened = {
        // something
      }
      MyComponent()
    }
    setupKeyboardDetection(findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content))
  }

  fun setupKeyboardDetection(contentView: View) {
    contentView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
      val r = Rect()
      contentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
      val screenHeight = contentView.rootView.height
      val keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom
      if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
        kbGone = false
        kbOpened()
      } else(!kbGone) {
        kbGone = true
        kbClosed()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 109):

## Update

With the new `WindowInsets` API, it gets easier

First, to return the correct values, you need to set:

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Then to use Keyboard as a state:

```
@Composable
fun keyboardAsState(): State<Boolean> {
    val isImeVisible = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(LocalDensity.current) > 0
    return rememberUpdatedState(isImeVisible)
}
```

use example:

```
val isKeyboardOpen by keyboardAsState() // true or false
```

*ps: I've tried to use WindowInsets.isImeVisible, but it returns true in the first call.*

---

### Without an experimental API

if you want with the statement, I found this solution:

```kotlin
enum class Keyboard {
    Opened, Closed
}

@Composable
fun keyboardAsState(): State<Keyboard> {
    val keyboardState = remember { mutableStateOf(Keyboard.Closed) }
    val view = LocalView.current
    DisposableEffect(view) {
        val onGlobalListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val rect = Rect()
            view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
            val screenHeight = view.rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom
            keyboardState.value = if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                Keyboard.Opened
            } else {
                Keyboard.Closed
            }
        }
        view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalListener)

        onDispose {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalListener)
        }
    }

    return keyboardState
}
```

and to detect/check the value you'll only need this:

```kotlin
val isKeyboardOpen by keyboardAsState() // Keyboard.Opened or Keyboard.Closed
```

Comment: very nice solution. thanks.

Comment: very nicely done!

Comment: Logging `isKeyboardOpen` shows rapid changes of the same value for me. Like 10 logs every second.

Comment: Oh never mind above, it was my composable being recompose rapidly

Comment: It stops working when I lock screen and unlock it again. Any idea why?

Comment: The state starts as closed but remains opened no matter the keyboard is shown or hidden.

Comment: Weird behavior oh my end. When first time whos the compose, WindowInsets.isImeVisible show true, but there is no keyboard shows, when tap on an input field, nothing is triggered. After I close the keyboard, WindowInsets.isImeVisible shows false. And I can get values change foward.

Comment: Hey @Arst, I just updated the answer, could you try again? Please make sure that you set `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` correctly too

Comment: I also pushed a sample here: https://github.com/ujizin/Compose-stackoverflow/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/ujizin/compose_stackoverflow/presentation/keyboard_state/KeyboardStateScreen.kt

Comment: @ujizin Thanks for the update. I ended up using `imePadding` for my case. I just needed to find way to adjust UI based on keyboard show/hide and found this one.

Comment: I get `Unresolved reference: ime` error and even after importing the recommended, this doesn't work.

Comment: I do keep getting wrong states when going back from the screen with open keyboard. Needs to be improved

Comment: Personaly the solution "Without an experimental API" works perfectly then the other is not working on my 29 api devices. May is some configuration that i'm using.
Ty !

Comment: Caution! Non experimental example has memory leak: when view/viewtreeobserver changes removeOnGlobalLayoutListener is called from incorrect object and listener isn't deleted, that causes view leak. Use fixed version: https://gist.github.com/MaxMyalkin/b63f4d4050e4ff882cf3a30abcab448f

Comment: The first option did work but it changes the screen size (edge-to-edge) which is not intended here, but the second option works, even though it shows a bit of lagginess but not really harmful

Comment: do not forget to set android:softInputMode to 'adjustResize' in AndroidManifest/yourActivity.

Comment: I found this github project [link](https://gist.github.com/abd3lraouf/8fb977996e52f23cd9315d1797e0c072) that indicates WindowInsets.isImeVisible needs enableEdgetoEdge() and found it worked for me as well. Still trying to understand why....

Answer (score 27):

Here is a solution that uses `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to **listen to changes** to the layout and uses the **new window insets APIs** to perform calculations, as recommended by [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/sw-keyboard). You can place this code anywhere inside a `@Composable` function and handle the `isKeyboardOpen` as you wish. I tested and it works on *API 21* and above.

```kotlin
val view = LocalView.current
val viewTreeObserver = view.viewTreeObserver
DisposableEffect(viewTreeObserver) {
    val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val isKeyboardOpen = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)
            ?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) ?: true
        // ... do anything you want here with `isKeyboardOpen`
    }

    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
    onDispose {
        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
    }
}
```

For me the other solutions wouldn't work well: the keyboard would result as always closed.

- In `OnGlobalLayoutListener`-based answers, the used formula does not seem to behave as it should, and **old APIs** are used.
- In the `WindowInsetListener`-based answer, since `view` is not the root view, **no window insets would be applied** on it. I tried replacing `view` with `view.rootView`, and although the keyboard-detection code would then work, passing the root view to `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` replaces any listener set by components, which is obviously unwanted.

Comment: This is pure genius

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this solution.

Comment: Working as expected and very well writter. Thank you!

Comment: Caution! This example has memory leak: when view/viewtreeobserver changes removeOnGlobalLayoutListener is called from incorrect object and listener isn't deleted, that causes view leak. Use fixed version: gist.github.com/MaxMyalkin/b63f4d4050e4ff882cf3a30abcab448f

Comment: @m.myalkin the difference is that you only store `view.viewTreeObserver` instead of the whole `view`, isn't it? If you confirm I will update my answer

Comment: @Stypox Also use DisposableEffect(viewTreeObserver).

From docs: The returned ViewTreeObserver observer is not guaranteed to remain valid for the lifetime of this View.

I.e. observer can change

Answer (score 7):

To handle the keyboard opening and closing behavior in Jetpack Compose without altering the `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` setting in your Activity, especially when working with a single activity architecture containing Fragments and Composables, you can use the following approach:

```
@Composable
fun keyboardAsState(): State<Boolean> {
    val view = LocalView.current
    var isImeVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    DisposableEffect(LocalWindowInfo.current) {
        val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            isImeVisible = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)
                ?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) == true
            true
        }
        view.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(listener)
        onDispose {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(listener)
        }
    }
    return rememberUpdatedState(isImeVisible)
}
```

This code snippet provides a Composable function `keyboardAsState` that allows you to observe and respond to changes in the keyboard's visibility status. It does so by leveraging the `DisposableEffect` and `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener` to detect when the keyboard opens or closes.

To use this function, simply access its value as `val isKeyboardOpen by keyboardAsState()` within your Composable where you need to track the keyboard state. It will return a `State<Boolean>` that reflects whether the keyboard is currently visible or not.

Comment: Tried a few others, but this works great for me!

Answer (score 3):

Detecting whether keyboard is opening or closing can be inspected with `WindowInsest.ime`

Set `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

To check whether it's open or close use

```
WindowInsets.isImeVisible
```

Check if it's going up or opening with using bottom offset however it's not always reliable you need to do extra steps to check if it's opening or closing

```
val offsetY = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(density)
```

you can compare a previous value and detect if it's opening closing, open or close

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73358604/5457853

When it opens it returns values such as

```
17:40:21.429  I  OffsetY: 1017
17:40:21.446  I  OffsetY: 38
17:40:21.463  I  OffsetY: 222
17:40:21.479  I  OffsetY: 438
17:40:21.496  I  OffsetY: 586
17:40:21.513  I  OffsetY: 685
17:40:21.530  I  OffsetY: 764
17:40:21.546  I  OffsetY: 825
17:40:21.562  I  OffsetY: 869
17:40:21.579  I  OffsetY: 907
17:40:21.596  I  OffsetY: 937
17:40:21.613  I  OffsetY: 960
17:40:21.631  I  OffsetY: 979
17:40:21.646  I  OffsetY: 994
17:40:21.663  I  OffsetY: 1004
17:40:21.679  I  OffsetY: 1010
17:40:21.696  I  OffsetY: 1014
17:40:21.713  I  OffsetY: 1016
17:40:21.730  I  OffsetY: 1017
17:40:21.746  I  OffsetY: 1017
```

While closing

```
17:40:54.276  I  OffsetY: 0
17:40:54.288  I  OffsetY: 972
17:40:54.303  I  OffsetY: 794
17:40:54.320  I  OffsetY: 578
17:40:54.337  I  OffsetY: 430
17:40:54.354  I  OffsetY: 331
17:40:54.371  I  OffsetY: 252
17:40:54.387  I  OffsetY: 191
17:40:54.404  I  OffsetY: 144
17:40:54.421  I  OffsetY: 109
17:40:54.437  I  OffsetY: 79
17:40:54.454  I  OffsetY: 55
17:40:54.471  I  OffsetY: 37
17:40:54.487  I  OffsetY: 22
17:40:54.504  I  OffsetY: 12
17:40:54.521  I  OffsetY: 6
17:40:54.538  I  OffsetY: 2
17:40:54.555  I  OffsetY: 0
17:40:54.571  I  OffsetY: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, with the new `WindowInsets` api, `WindowInsets.isImeVisible` can be used. For reference, see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets.Companion).isImeVisible()).

Answer (score 1):

Also we can use `WindowInsetListener`, something like this

```kotlin
@Composable
fun keyboardAsState(): State<Boolean> {
    val keyboardState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val view = LocalView.current
    LaunchedEffect(view) {
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { _, insets ->
            keyboardState.value = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
            insets
        }
    }
    return keyboardState
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The state remains same whether or not keyboard is visible.

Comment: Because you have to Set `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` in mainActivity

Answer (score 0):

In Jetpack compose:

```
@Composable
fun isKeyboardVisible(): Boolean = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(LocalDensity.current) > 0
```

It will return true or false,

**True -> Keyboard Visible**

**False -> Keyboard Not Visible**

Comment: What if monitoring is required?

Comment: Can you explain in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
@Composable
fun OnKeyboardClosedEffect(block: () -> Unit) {
    val isKeyboardVisible = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(LocalDensity.current) > 130
    var keyboardListenerHaBeenSet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (isKeyboardVisible || keyboardListenerHaBeenSet) {
        if (!isKeyboardVisible) {
            block()
            keyboardListenerHaBeenSet = false // clear
        }
        keyboardListenerHaBeenSet = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

New Experimental solution:

```
val isImeVisible = WindowInsets.isImeVisible
```

Comment: At least in a bottom sheet this is not working, don't know why.