# Jetpack Compose Intercept back button from soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to intercept back button when keyboard is open? With EditText it's possible as in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard/5811630#5811630), is it possible for Compose either?

I have a `Search` Composable that invokes a search after 300ms debounce and when i click back press i want not only close keyboard but remove focus and clear query either.

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

val dispatcher: OnBackPressedDispatcher =
    LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current!!.onBackPressedDispatcher

val backCallback = remember {
    object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (!state.focused) {
                isEnabled = false
                Toast.makeText(context, "Back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                dispatcher.onBackPressed()
            } else {
                println("HomeScreen() Search Back ")
                state.query = TextFieldValue("")
                state.focused = false
                focusManager.clearFocus()
                keyboardController?.hide()
            }
        }
    }
}

DisposableEffect(dispatcher) { // dispose/relaunch if dispatcher changes
    dispatcher.addCallback(backCallback)
    onDispose {
        backCallback.remove() // avoid leaks!
    }
}
```

Back search is only triggered after keyboard is closed as you can see in gif, it does another search after keyboard is closed because query is not empty.

Note, I don't want a solution to prevent doing another query, adding a previous query check does that, i want to intercept keyboard back press so **only** the block inside `handleOnBackPressed` is triggered when system back button is pressed when keyboard is open not after keyboard is closed.

[image]

`SearchState` is

```
class SearchState<I, R, S>(
    initialResults: List<I>,
    suggestions: List<S>,
    searchResults: List<R>,
) {
    var query by mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
    var focused by mutableStateOf(false)
    var initialResults by mutableStateOf(initialResults)
    var suggestions by mutableStateOf(suggestions)
    var searchResults by mutableStateOf(searchResults)
    
    var searching by mutableStateOf(false)
    var searchInProgress = searching

    val searchDisplay: SearchDisplay
        get() = when {
            !focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.InitialResults
            focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Suggestions
            searchInProgress -> SearchDisplay.SearchInProgress
            !searchInProgress && searchResults.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.NoResults
            else -> SearchDisplay.Results
        }

}
```

And query is processed with

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    snapshotFlow { state.query }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .filter {
            it.text.isNotEmpty()
        }
        .map {
            state.searching = false
            state.searchInProgress = true
            it
        }
        .debounce(300)
        .mapLatest {
            state.searching = true
            delay(300)
            viewModel.getTutorials(it.text)
        }
        .collect {
            state.searchInProgress = false
            state.searching = false
            state.searchResults = it
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Thracian, I'm not sure if I have to open another thread post about this, though I think I'm having the same issue and unable to find any good source about this, do you have any update on this?.. thank you.

Comment: There is linked question asks the same thing. Abhimanyu opened an issue for this. It's still open. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241705563

Comment: Let's hope it gets added in the future. I saw another question asking same thing recently.

Comment: Yep, though just to mention, for my use-case, I followed certain posts on how to detect if the `softkeyboard` is open or closed, and just defined a callback to listen to the changes, so far it serves its purpose, but having this issue resolved and covered in compose would simplify such workarounds. Thank you again @Thracian

Comment: Same. I used a workaround for the question above either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add this to your textFeild modifier

```
.onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard {
                    if (it.key == Key.Back) {
                        // handle back
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                    }
                    false
                }
```

Return true to stop propagation of this event. If you return false, the key event will be sent to this SoftKeyboardInterceptionModifierNode's child.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extension function to handle the same:

```
fun Modifier.onKeyboardDismiss(handleOnBackPressed: () -> Unit): Modifier = 
    composed {
    this.onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard {
        if (it.key.keyCode == 17179869184) {
            handleOnBackPressed.invoke()
        }
        true
    }
}
```

This feature was added to the latest version of Jetpack Compose. using the function **onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard** I am just intercepting the hide keyboard button which had a code of **17179869184**, and giving my own implementation, the use case was to hide the bottom sheet if the keyboard is dismissed and this met my requirement, could not find a doc related to this if you guys saw one please do add it here. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: works!!! and yes if only we had documentation for this...

Answer (score 2):

Using [ujizin's solution on Oct 11, 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533584) for the SO post `How can I detect keyboard opening and closing in jetpack compose`, I managed to make it work like a charm!

**Example**

```
var prevKeyboardState by remember { mutableStateOf(KeyboardState.Closed) }
val keyboardState by keyboardAsState()

LaunchedEffect(keyboardState) {

    if (prevKeyboardState == KeyboardState.Opened) {
        /* any actions on Keyboard close */
    }

    prevKeyboardState = keyboardState

}
```

**KeyboardState.kt**

```
enum class KeyboardState {
    Opened, Closed
}


@Composable
fun keyboardAsState(): State<KeyboardState> {

    val keyboardState = remember { mutableStateOf(KeyboardState.Closed) }
    val view = LocalView.current

    DisposableEffect(view) {

        val onGlobalListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

            val rect = Rect()

            view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)

            val screenHeight = view.rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom

            keyboardState.value = if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                KeyboardState.Opened
            } else {
                KeyboardState.Closed
            }

        }

        view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalListener)

        onDispose {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalListener)
        }

    }

    return keyboardState

}
```

Comment: Explain why your solution works. Don't post only code.

Answer (score 0):

try modifier event onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard

reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/key/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard(kotlin.Function1)

```
OutlinedTextField(
value = "",
onValueChange = { },
label = { Text("Name") },
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done,

    ),
keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
    onDone = {
        // handle value when keyboard done clicked
    }
),
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard { event ->
        if (event.key.nativeKeyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // handle value when device back button clicked
            true

        } else {
            false

        }
    }
```

)