# Handle back button click when keyboard is open in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, back-button

The below-provided code is a simplified version of my problem.

I want to trigger an action when the device back button is clicked when the keyboard is open.

It is possible to handle the back button click using `BackHandler` when the keyboard is closed. But I want it even if the keyboard is open.

```
@Composable
fun BackHandlingWhenKeyboardOpen() {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    BackHandler(
        enabled = true,
    ) {
        // This is not triggered when keyboard is open
        Log.d("TEST_TAG", "Back Handler")
    }
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(
                indication = null,
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
            ) {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onDone = {
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                },
            ),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I asked similar question here yet no answer. I think it's not possible yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361664/jetpack-compose-intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard

Comment: Thanks, @Thracian for pointing it out. Please upvote this issue if this helps - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241705563

Answer (score 0):

try modifier event onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard

reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/key/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard(kotlin.Function1)

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = "",
    onValueChange = { },
    label = { Text("Name") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Done,

        ),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = {
            // handle value when keyboard done clicked
        }
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard { event ->
            if (event.key.nativeKeyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                // handle value when device back button clicked
                true

            } else {
                false

            }
        }
)
```