# Show keyboard over Scaffold's bottomBar in Jetpack Compose and apply proper inset paddings

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, windowinsets, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using `Scaffold` for my main screen with a fixed `bottomBar` that is visible in every screen of the app, and I'm applying the `innerPadding` of the `Scaffold` to its content.

I want the keyboard to appear over the `bottomBar`, and for that I'm applying the `imePadding()` only to the `Scaffold`'s content.

However, when the keyboard is opened, both the `Scaffold`'s `innerPading` and `imePadding()` are applied to the contents padding.

I've tried to go through the [Accompanist Insets migration](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/), but no lucky.

Is there anyway that I can prevent it and apply only one or the other?

Here is a piece of my code:

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    topBar = { },
    bottomBar = { },
    modifier = Modifier
        .systemBarsPadding()
) { innerPadding ->
    Content(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(innerPadding)
            .imePadding()
    )
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

With the now, deprecated, Accompanist Insets, I was using the following solution:

```kotlin
val isImeVisible = LocalWindowInsets.current.ime.isVisible
val contentPadding = remember(isImeVisible) {
    if (isImeVisible) PaddingValues(top = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding()) else innerPadding
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since **1.4.0** you can use system `WindowInsets.isImeVisible`. For 1.3.0 see answer below:

According to [Accompanist Insets migration](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/), `LocalWindowInsets.current.ime` should be replaced with `WindowInsets.ime`.

It doesn't have `isVisible` for now, until this [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217770337) is fixed. Here's how I've re-created it for now:

```
val WindowInsets.Companion.isImeVisible: Boolean
    @Composable
    get() {
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val ime = this.ime
        return remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                ime.getBottom(density) > 0
            }
        }.value
    }
```

Usage:

```
val isImeVisible = WindowInsets.isImeVisible
```

This should work with your old `remember(isImeVisible)` code.

Comment: Can we listen to the keyboard open/close state changes using this approach?

Comment: @SpiralDev in compose instead of listening for changes we're reacting on state changes, which trigger recomposition of the view which is using this particular state. E.g. you can write `if (WindowInsets.isImeVisible) Text("visible") else Text("hidden")`, if you need to launch some action, you can do this with `LaunchedEffect`: `if (WindowInsets.isImeVisible) LaunchedEffect(Unit) { doSomeStuff }`.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533584/5985958) then, It detects state changes?

Comment: @SpiralDev I'm not saying that you can't, sometimes you have to, like in the linked case, when you need to deal with old Android API.

Comment: So now that Compose 1.4 is released, which should contain the fix, do you know how to replace the custom method?

Comment: @G00fY there's system `WindowInsets.isImeVisible` now

Answer (score 2):

Try using something like this (WARNING: consumedWindowInsets is Experimental, but it's working):

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = { },
    bottomBar = { },
    modifier = Modifier
        .systemBarsPadding()
) { innerPadding ->
    Content(
        modifier = Modifier
            .consumedWindowInsets(innerPadding)
            .padding(innerPadding)
            .imePadding()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to set `BringIntoViewRequester` to your content inside Scaffold. Then when textField is focused, you could call `bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()`. This way you wouldn't need to set any paddings.

```
val bringIntoViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)
) {
    TextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {},
        modifier = Modifier
            .onFocusEvent {
                if (it.isFocused) {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        delay(350)
                        bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                    }
                }
            }
    )
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that onFocusEvent callback will be triggered after opening or closing the keyboard, and on each value change - that's a lot of callbacks.
Also, adding delay() seems to solve the problem of consuming the callback on recomposition.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've adopted in my app:

1. In AndroidManifest.xml add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the activity
2. In Activity::onCreate add `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`
3. In the composable:

```
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { },
        bottomBar = { }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        val topPadding = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding()
        val bottomPadding = max(
            innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding(),
            WindowInsets.ime.asPaddingValues().calculateBottomPadding()
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(PaddingValues(top = topPadding, bottom = bottomPadding))
        )
    }
```

This way the animation works well when the keyboard opens / closes.