# Android Jetpack Compose statusbar height?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, statusbar

How can I get the statusbar height?
Accompanist Insets is now deprecated, and `WindowInsets.systemBars.asPaddingValues()` gives me 0 every time...
And `Modifier.statusBarsPadding()` does nothing in my layout.
Is there any way to get this height?!?

Comment: https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode/tree/master/lib/utilcode#about-bar---barutilsjava---demo

Comment: Did you call `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When i call `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` before setContent on Activity i get correct values otherwise it returns 0

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable() {
    Column {
        val paddingValues = WindowInsets.systemBars.asPaddingValues()
        Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(paddingValues.calculateTopPadding()))
        Text(text = "Padding values: $paddingValues")
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Without `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the statusbar height using:

```
val statusBarHeight = WindowInsets.statusBars.asPaddingValues().calculateTopPadding()
```

If you want to use the height just as a modifier:
(From the accompanist migration table: https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/#migration-table)

```
Modifier.windowInsetsTopHeight(WindowInsets.statusBars)
```

Comment: When I log WindowInsets.statusBars, i get this: statusBars(0, 0, 0, 0)  

So the statusBarHeight is 0 too..
The modifier is not working either, my Box disappears when I set this modifier... :(