# How can I selectively disable android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" from manifest file?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-input-method

Initially I want to show a composable immediately on top of the Android default keyboard, what slides in if needed on my different screens. [Similar like in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73331594/how-can-i-show-a-composable-on-top-of-the-visible-keyboard), but I do **not** want to set `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`, which would be required for this solution.

Therefore, I've set in the manifestv for that Activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

And aligned stuff I want to display immediately on top of the keyboard to `Alignment.Bottom`.

For the very same activity, I also have a use case, where the keyboard slides in, but I do not want to align it on top of the keyboard. it shall remain on the the same position as it was without keyboard.

Can I selectively tell a composable to ignore `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, which was already set for the whole Activity?