# State Holder in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-architecture-components

I am learning in [State](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) in jetpack compose. I found that [State holders as source of truth](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-holder-source-of-truth). So created my some data can you guys guide me if I am doing wrong here.

**PairViewModel.kt**

```
class PairViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var isBluetoothEnabled = mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    fun onBluetoothEnable(value: Boolean) {
        isBluetoothEnabled.value = value
    }
}
```

**PairScreen.kt**

```
class PairScreenState(context: Context, viewModel: PairViewModel) {

    private val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
    private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter by lazy {
        bluetoothManager.adapter
    }

    init {
        viewModel.onBluetoothEnable(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled)
    }

    fun checkBluetoothStatus(bluetoothStatus: MutableState<Boolean>): BroadcastReceiver {
        return object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                if (intent?.action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
                    when (intent.getIntExtra(
                        BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        BluetoothAdapter.ERROR
                    )) {
                        BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> {
                            bluetoothStatus.value = false
                        }
                        BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> {
                            bluetoothStatus.value = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun rememberPairScreenState(
    context: Context,
    viewModel: PairViewModel
) = remember {
    PairScreenState(context, viewModel)
}

@Composable
fun PairContent(
    context: Context = LocalContext.current,
    viewModel: PairViewModel = getViewModel(),
    rememberPairScreenState: PairScreenState = rememberPairScreenState(context, viewModel),
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = true) {
        AppBarScaffold() {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                rememberPairScreenState.checkBluetoothStatus(viewModel.isBluetoothEnabled).apply {
                    context.registerReceiver(this, IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED))
                }
                if (viewModel.isBluetoothEnabled.value) {
                    println(">> Enable >>>")
                } else {
                    println(">> Disable >>>")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PairContentPreview() {
    PairContent()
}
```

I am using Bluetooth as example to understand state holder in my use case. Please guide me if you find anything wrong in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ill try my best here, I get where you're coming from, having a code that it's hard to verify if its the proper way of doing "**yet**", regardless of how many source materials you review like in `github`, sometimes references just doesn't exist **yet** right?

For `State` hoisting/handling, its good to follow the principles coming from the community. So the way I handle `State Hoisting`, is thinking of its `purpose`

So if its just something that needs to be local within the `@Composable`

```
remember {...}
```

If its something that deals with multiple logic and values, `State` class

```
class PersonState(val personParam: Person) {
        .....
}

@Composable 
fun rememberPersonState(person: Person) = remember(key1= person) {
       PersonState(person)
}
```

If its something that deals with repository, network calls, use-cases where persistence is a major part of the requirement, `ViewModel`, and `lifecyle` is something you have to be aware of. `ViewModel`

```
class PersonScreenViewModel {
     /..RepositoryStateFlows../
     /..Data structural updates../
}
```

So far this mindset and approach helped me a bit when deciding how would I hoist my `states`.

As for your **PairScreenState**, consider this use-case solution  coming from this post [Detect if Soft Keyboard is Open or Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847559/how-can-i-detect-keyboard-opening-and-closing-in-jetpack-compose), where you can detect if the keyboard is open or not

I would have your BlueTooth usecase where I would implement it as a `Composable` utility function and returns a `State` where I can define a `DisposableEffect`, though this code is not working but I think you'll get my point here.

```
enum class BlueTooth {
    ON, OFF
}

@Composable
fun BlueToothAsState(): State<BlueTooth> {
    val blueToothState = remember { mutableStateOf(BlueTooth.OFF) }
    DisposableEffect(view) {
        var mReceiver : BroadcastReceiver? = object : BroadcastReceiver()  {
                /.../
                when (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,  BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)) {
                        BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> {
                            blueToothState = BlueTooth.OFF
                        }
                        BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> {
                            blueToothState = BlueTooth.ON
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        onDispose {
            mReceiver = null
        }
    }

    return blueToothState
}
```

As for the other parts of the code, I don't think you need it here if its just always set to `true`

```
 AnimatedVisibility(visible = true)
```

Comment: What is your option on using a StateHolder class in conjunction with a ViewModel? In a application I was working in, I had my business logic hoisted into the ViewModel but logic relating to the UI such as if a field should be hidden or holding other composable state objects like ScrollState, ScaffoldState. I like this design because UI rules aren't bleeding into the viewModel; therefore the VM are more pure and UI framework agnostic. I feel this design would help support Views or Jetpack Compose. I haven't seen any examples using this design so I wonder if it's not recommended.