# Observing Soft Keyboard Visibility, Opened/Closed Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, compose-recomposition

I'm trying to actively observe the soft keyboard visibility, currently, I'm trying to observe it with

```
WindowInsets.isImeVisible
```

but I can't seem to observe its state change. Someone mentioned using

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener()
```

but I can't quite understand how to implement this to observe the keyboard visibility.

I have managed to use

```
WindowInsets.isImeVisible
```

however, it only applies at the time I navigate to the page and the keyboard auto opens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from this [S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847559/how-can-i-detect-keyboard-opening-and-closing-in-jetpack-compose) post,

You can use this to check if the `keyboard` is **opened** or **closed**

```
internal enum class Keyboard {
    Opened, Closed
}

@Composable
internal fun keyboardAsState(): State<Keyboard> {
    val keyboardState = remember { mutableStateOf(Keyboard.Closed) }
    val view = LocalView.current
    DisposableEffect(view) {
        val onGlobalListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val rect = Rect()
            view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
            val screenHeight = view.rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom
            keyboardState.value = if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                Keyboard.Opened
            } else {
                Keyboard.Closed
            }
        }
        view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalListener)

        onDispose {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalListener)
        }
    }

    return keyboardState
}
```

You can test it like this,

```
@Composable
fun KeyboardCheck() {

    val keyboard by keyboardAsState()

    Log.e("KeyboardCheck", "$keyboard")

    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
}
```

and every time the keyboard opens and closes it will print

```
E/KeyboardCheck: Closed
E/KeyboardCheck: Opened
E/KeyboardCheck: Closed
E/KeyboardCheck: Opened
E/KeyboardCheck: Closed
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was spot on, now I just need to figure out how to adjust the focus so that my the pointer on screen is the POI