# Is it possible to have a dialog box attached to the virtual keyboard?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am currently working on a Client project and I have been asked to see if its possible to remove the space between a dialog box and the virtual keyboard. For example when the User clicks on the a text field on a dialog box and the keyboard appears, I want the keyboard to appear directly under the dialog box with no space in between. This is proving to be difficult because a dialog box its automatically centers on the screen.

[image: This is what I have.]

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: I don't think this is possible with actual Dialog. But you can create fake dialog - it will be normal compose screen with scrim and card on top which you can position exactly as you need. It might be difficult to replicate the exact dialog behavior though.

Comment: Agree with @JanBína. You can create one composable which will be aligned at BottomCenter with AnimatedVisibility which will be visible only when Keyboard is open! Also, you will have to set softInputMode to `adjustResize`. You can know keyboard state from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847559/how-can-i-detect-keyboard-opening-and-closing-in-jetpack-compose#:~:text=OnPreDrawListener%20to%20detect%20when%20the,is%20currently%20visible%20or%20not.

Comment: Also you can refer my this answer for changing `softInputMode` and maybe this answer can help you in this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76617537/19212377

Comment: Yeah, I figured their would be any other way besides a custom composable. I appreciate the feedback.