# Jetpack compose, how to hide topAppBar and Drawer when entering in some screens

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have different screens specified on my app, but I would like in some of them just the topAppBar, or just the drawer, or both in other cases. How would I hide them? I've seen a way to store the route in a State and check the routes i want to show those components with an if but. Is there any other way to do it instead of comparing the routes every time?

Thanks :)

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BaseAuthScreen(navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()) {
    
    // Get the route and compare it?

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            AuthGraph(navHostController = navController)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can take reference from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76617537/19212377 . There is logic for hiding bottom bar on the basis of current route